# Why does Norway use the word "returned" instead of "elected"?

Tags: norway

From [Norway's page](https://www.regjeringen.no/en/topics/elections-and-democracy/den-norske-valgordningen/the-norwegian-electoral-system/id456636/#en) describing the structure of their government:

> The number of members returned to the Storting is 169. The number of members to be returned from each constituency depends on the population and area of the county. Each inhabitant counts one point, while each square kilometre counts 1.8 points. Of the 169 members returned, 150 are elected as constituency representatives while 19, one seat from each constituency, are elected as members at large.

Notice they say *returned* instead of *elected*. Actually, the word *elected* appears 14 times on the page while *returned* appears 16 times. I would just like to understand the nuance here better. Does the Norwegian system make some distinction which causes the word *returned* to be more accurately descriptive of what's happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a use in British English. The MP is returned to Parliament. The official who organises the count of votes is the Returning Officer. In British English, "returned" is a synonym for "elected".

Naturally, the Norwegian system would be better described in Norwegian, and I don't think there is any subtle nuance here. The author just wants to use some variation in language.

Comment: In case anyone's interested. A UK general election is formally called by issuing Writs of Election to each constituency. The role of the Returning Officer is to ensure that the election is correctly carried out then *return* the name of the duly elected representative to Parliament. Hence the use of returning in this context.

Comment: Yes, any nuance in the English translation is irrelevant with regards to the authoritative Norwegian text (which uses *representant*, e.g *representative*).